# How to hide specific dom element in html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, export

I uses following plugins to export table data in PNG,

```
<li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false', ignoreColumn:[0, 4]});"> <img src='icons/xls.png' width='24px'> XLS</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'doc',escape:'false', ignoreColumn:[0, 4]});"> <img src='icons/word.png' width='24px'> Word</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'png',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/png.png' width='24px'> PNG</a></li>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tableExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

And the output like this,
[image]
Here I want to hide 'Photos' and 'Options' columns I checked this https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/126 but not getting it so how can Ido this.

Comment: is this table format or div based?

Comment: @BhavinSolanki- table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tabular format, you can use `firs-child` and `last-child` to get access of first and last column of table.

```
$("#tableID th:first-child, #tableID th:last-child, #tableID td:first-child, #tableID td:last-child").hide();
```

OR

```
$("#tableID tr th:first-child, #tableID tr th:last-child, #tableID tr td:first-child, #tableID tr td:last-child").hide();
```

You need to hide element before using html2canvas rendering .

After html2canvas rendering , you needto use show() function to display hidden td. so it would be like :

```
 $("#tableID th:first-child, #tableID th:last-child, #tableID td:first-child, #tableID td:last-child").show();
```

OR

```
 $("#tableID tr th:first-child, #tableID tr th:last-child, #tableID tr td:first-child, #tableID tr td:last-child").show();
```

So this way you don't need to refresh your page .

Comment: It works fine, I changed <li><a href="#" onClick ="pngHide();$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'png',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/png.png' width='24px'> PNG</a></li> but the problem is, for showing original actual output it requires 'page refresh' and it is inconvenient. Can we solve this problem in plugin itself or any new idea from you?

Comment: after completing html2canvas rendering you need to call .show() to hide() element so in this way you don't need to refresh page

Comment: i have update code for show hide() td.... you need to add that after completion of h2ml2canvas render